# libquadmath error on CentOS 6: not found by software

Tags: centos, shared-libraries

A piece of software I compiled on a CentOS 6 machine is giving me an error that I don't see with the exact same software compiled on my Ubuntu 14.10 laptop:

```
auxgen: error while loading shared libraries: libquadmath.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The library in question does seem to be there on the CentOS machine:

```
$ locate libquadmath
/usr/local/lib/libquadmath.a
/usr/local/lib/libquadmath.la
/usr/local/lib/libquadmath.so
/usr/local/lib/libquadmath.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
/usr/local/lib64/libquadmath.a
/usr/local/lib64/libquadmath.la
/usr/local/lib64/libquadmath.so
/usr/local/lib64/libquadmath.so.0
/usr/local/lib64/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
/usr/local/share/info/libquadmath.info

$ ldd /usr/local/bin/auxgen
/usr/local/bin/auxgen: /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/auxgen)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6cdb0000)
    libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x0000003b64a00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x000000330d000000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003c0b400000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000330c400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000330c000000)
```

On my Ubuntu 14.10 laptop, where it works:

```
    $ ldd /usr/local/bin/auxgen
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7aaf2000)
    libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007fd71b5da000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd71b215000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007fd71afd6000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd71acd0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd71aab9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd71b922000)
```

On the Ubuntu laptop where it does work:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep 'quad\|gfort'
    libquadmath.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0
    libgfortran.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3
```

On the CentOS where it doesn't work:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep 'quad\|gfort'
    libgfortran.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3
    libgfortran.so.3 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgfortran.so.3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you run `ldconfig` (as root) since installing the `libquadmath` library?

Comment: I just did `sudo -s -H` and then `ldconfig` and it runs silently with no errors.

Comment: Yes, that's all `ldconfig` does. Does `auxgen` work now though?

Comment: Yes, still same error. Added more info to the q.

Comment: What does `ldconfig -p | grep 'quad\|gfort'` return?

Comment: added more info to the q.

Comment: Does `ldconfig -p | grep /local/` output anything? You might need to add `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/lib64/` to a file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` and re-run `ldconfig` if it doesn't since CentOS looks like it might not include those paths in the ld configuration by default.